# Un verbe peut-il avoir deux COD ?

Tags: syntaxe, comparaison-de-langues, compléments, transitivité

En anglais on peut dire "I gave Tom an apple", "j'ai donné une pomme à Tom". Dans l'exemple, il y a en français un COD et un COI, alors qu'en anglais il n'y a aucune préposition (pour les distinguer il faut donc absolument les mettre dans le bon ordre). Existe-t-il des cas similaires en français ?

Comment: Tu pourrais considérer "j'ai peint la porte rouge" pour avoir une syntaxe parallèle, mais ce n'est toujours pas deux COD :)

Comment: @Luke: On dit plutôt *peindre la porte en rouge* dans ce cas-là.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Citons donc « On me rend fou » à la place :)

Comment: Cf. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31563/i-gave-tom-an-apple-and-i-gave-an-apple-to-tom

Comment: @MathieuBouville The answer to your question on the linguistics beta is [here](https://www.grammarbank.com/double-object-verbs.html): two objects, one direct, the other indirect (with a preposition or **not**) and the dative is not considered as a particularity to contend with (the grammarians of English have adopted a simplified view).

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ce que tu veux dire par « pour les distinguer il faut donc absolument les mettre dans le bon ordre » parce que si on change l'ordre on a un COD et un COI, *I gave an apple to Tom*. Et dans le cas extrême où on aurait deux noms propres en complément, on utilise aussi un COD et un COI (*I gave Jim to John* - Jim étant le nom du chien - *I gave John Jim* ne se dirait pas).

Comment: @LukeSawczak : à propos de ton exemple en comment #3. Non! Un seul COD : *me*. *fou* est ici attribut.

Comment: @aCOSwt Quite right, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

Si on sort de la question les cas d'énumération (*J'enseigne la musique et les mathématiques*) dans lesquels c'est l'énumération qui sera tenue tout entière pour syntagme nominal complément d'objet direct et non chacun de ses membres individuellement, on réalise que la double complémentation objectale ne peut concerner que les **verbes à trois actants** : Un sujet et deux objets.

Riegel observe que *"Ces verbes dénotent une opération concrète ou figurée de transfert entre deux des actants."*

Les deux objets de ces verbes jouent donc chacun un **rôle (sémantique)** différent. Pour être cohérent, on doit donc leur conférer deux **fonctions** différentes.

Si un des deux objets est dit direct => l'autre ne peut pas l'être => exit toute possibilité de double complémentation directe.

Une telle logique nous permettra de répondre à la question du titre : NON!

---

L'illusion de la possibilité d'une double complémentation directe nous vient du latin ainsi que d'une définition exclusivement (morpho)syntaxique du COD.

L'accusatif est le (seul et unique) cas correspondant au complément d'objet direct.

- **Doceo aliquid** : (*I teach something / J'enseigne quelque chose*)

*aliquid*, accusatif neutre d'*aliquid* <=> COD (en latin) => dans mes traductions.

- **Doceo aliquem** : (*I teach somebody / J'instruis quelqu'un*)

*aliquem* accusatif masculin d'*aliquis* <=> COD (en latin) => dans mes traductions.

C'est là qu'on rigole : Le latin peut sans problème combiner les deux phrases ci-dessus dans un :

- **Doceo aliquem aliquid** : (*I teach somebody something* / Heuu... la traduction française devra attendre...)

Deux accusatifs <=> deux COD-latin dans la même phrase!
L'appellation COD n'existant pas en latin, on dira plus formellement une telle construction à *double accusatif.*

L'ordre des mots étant, en latin, très souvent laissé à la discrétion de l'auteur, ce n'est pas sur lui qu'il faudra compter pour distinguer les deux. C'est alors sur la distinction animé / inanimé (inférable à partir du genre (N vs M ou F) que le lecteur se basera.

---

On voit dans l'exemple du paragraphe précédent que l'anglais peut sans problème traduire mot à mot. Mais... comme le dit l'OP, **il faut impérativement respecter un ordre.**

Eh oui! C'est que contrairement au latin, il n'est pas question de genre an anglais, le lecteur devra donc se fonder sur ce qui reste syntaxiquement à manger à la recherche d'une **asymétrie** dans la construction.

Un linguiste a démontré que, dans le cas des verbes trivalents, (l'anglais les dit ***ditransitive***) seule une asymétrie de construction peut permettre de distinguer les deux objets.

Cette asymétrie peut tout à fait être assurée par jeu sur la position respective des deux objets dans la phrase.

Pour des raisons sur lesquelles les linguistes divergent, l'usage a consacré l'ordre (S V O2 O1) en tant qu'ordre canonique avec O2 dit *secondary object* plus proche du verbe qu'O1 dit *primary object* qui se trouve être le plus souvent direct.

*I teach someone something*

L'asymétrie pourrait aussi être introduite par l'intervention d'une préposition permettant de ne plus devoir se préoccuper de l'ordre et donc :

[S V O1 prep O2] ou [S V prep O2 O1]

*I teach something to someone* ou *I teach to someone something*

Answer (score -1):

En anglais on ne parlerais que de « deux compléments d'objets » ([two objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb)); en français il n'est jamais question de deux COD mais il peut être question de deux CO et alors l'un est un [COS](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/COS.php) selon la nouvelle grammaire (traditionnellement un COI, COS signifiant « CO secondaire »). De plus, dans le cas présent le français considère que le second complément (vous) relève d'une fonction différente de celle du COI, celle-ci étant le datif ou couramment ce qui est appelé le complément d'attribution.

La nomenclature mise à part, il existe des cas similaires, bien sûr, mais il n'existe  pas véritablement un problème de distinction par l'ordre, ni en français ni en anglais (sauf si une préposition n'est pas utilisée) ; l'ordre est plutôt une question d'usage et en français il ne s'agit pas d'un ordre unique ; il dépend de la personne lorsque des pronoms objet sont utilisés ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+nous+l%27a+dit%2Cil+le+leur+a+dit&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20nous%20l%27%20a%20dit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20le%20leur%20a%20dit%3B%2Cc0)). Cependant, ces cas seraient limités à des contextes où les compléments sont des pronoms, une préposition semblant toujours être nécessaire lorsque le COI ou le complément d'attribution n'est pas un pronom ;

- Nous le leur avons dit hier.
- Elle nous l'a dit hier.
- Il leur livre du lait tous les matins ; il le leur apporte de bonne heure.

La distinction se fait à la fois sur la base de la nature des mots, pronom objet direct (le, la, les ), pronom COI (lui, leur, vous, …) et sur l'ordre ; l'ordre seul ne suffit pas ; par exemple, si on écrit « I give an apple Tom. » on distingue le COD au moyen de la nature des mots et on conclut qu'il y a une faute et qu'il faut écrire « I give an apple to Tom. ». Cela est confirmé [ici](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb), à la fin du second paragraphe.

Comment: Ces exemples sont artificiels, basés sur le fait que les pronoms ne prennent pas de préposition même comme COI. J'ai changé la question pour éviter cette confusion.

Comment: @MathieuBouville J'ai toujours trouvé que dans ce cas, où le verbe « donner » est utilisé dans son sens premier (pas comme dans « donner du fil à retordre à quelqu'un ») on parlait de complément d'attribution, du datif et non de l'accusatif ; pourquoi référer à un COI ?

Comment: It's not true that in English we *only* say that such a verb has "two objects". It's normal to call them a direct and an indirect object, as in French.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I don't think you can force that interpretation: what's to be understood is that you can **say** only "two objects" not "two **direct** objects". I said that as you say it for instance in the first sentence you find from the first link (two objects): "In grammar, a ditransitive verb is a verb which takes a subject and two objects which refer to a theme and a recipient.". By the way, that's just what the title of the question implies: a verb in English could have two direct objects; that's what has to be denied.

Comment: Un COI est indirect parce qu'il y a une préposition. Le datif n'est pas directement lié aux prépositions (latin, allemand). Dans mon exemple, on peut certainement parler de datif, mais COI me parait problématique.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Traditionnellement il ne s'agit que de datif, ou comme on nous l'enseignait dans les écoles primaires il y a cinquante ans, du [complément d'attribution](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/compl%C3%A9ment_d%E2%80%99attribution).