# Pourquoi ne peut-on pas dire « Je t’aime [qqch] » ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

Pourquoi, pour d’autres verbes comme par exemple « manger », ces deux phrases sont justes et équivalentes :

- Je mange ton bras
- Je te mange le bras

…tandis que pour « aimer » :

- J’aime tes jambes
- <s>Je t’aime les jambes</s>

…ce n’est pas le cas ? Quelle est la règle qui empêche « Je t’aime les jambes » d’être grammaticalement correct ?

Comment: Mais on peut dire *je t'aime le lundi* ;-)

Comment: (https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34858/un-verbe-peut-il-avoir-deux-cod/34859#34859)[https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34858/un-verbe-peut-il-avoir-deux-cod/34859#34859]

Answer (score 1):

Je ne vois pas ce qui empêche « grammaticalement » de dire « je t'aime les jambes ». C'est une tournure qui n'est pas employée, certes. Pour autant, si un écrivain un peu célèbre l'avait imposée, elle serait entrée dans le dictionnaire. Si on s'attarde quelques minutes sur la phrase « je t'aime les jambes », on finit par en saisir le sens parfaitement. Cela pourrait même intégrer le langage amoureux.

Le Trésor de la langue française contient une quantité phénoménale de tournures exotiques de ce genre, référencées par des écrits rares pour ne pas dire inconnus du commun des mortels.